# How to make Key Images in questions?

Tags: support

I've been trying to answer questions but I want to add The little keys in there, and I don't know how. How do I do it?

Answer (score 7):

Put `<kbd></kbd>` around anything you want to make into a key. For instance `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>` becomes:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

**For the future:** if you have any questions like this, press the [edit] button below the question or answer you're seeing this and you'll get the source.  Then press <kbd>Cancel</kbd> to get back out!  **;-)**